# Get val() from textarea

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<textarea name="input" cols="50" rows="10" id="input"></textarea>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="Go" />
<br /><br />
<textarea name="output" cols="50" rows="10" id="output"></textarea>
```

Then I input the following html into the (#input textarea) on browser. How can I click the go button and get 'Some text 1' by id block1 and show it in the (#output textarea).

```
<div id="block1">Some text 1<div>
<div id="block2">Some text 2<div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
$('#output').val( {{{#input.val-->#block1.val}}} );
});
```

My aim is type some html in #input textarea, then it will replace the text by id and output in #output textarea ....

Comment: try $('#output').html()

By the way.. missing quotes.. typo??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, your question is a bit confusing, but I think I get the idea. You want to type HTML in your textarea, then parse it with JQuery to get the value of `block1`, and then output that into another textarea.

This will work:

```
//get the input value (html)
var input = $("#input").val();

//convert to JQuery object
var html = $("<div/>");
html.html(input);

//get the value of block1
var block1 = html.find("#block1").text();

//set this to output
$("#output").val(block1);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUdYR/), but you need to make sure your input html is valid...

```
<div id="block1">Some text 1</div>
<div id="block2">Some text 2</div>
```

notice the use of `</div>`

Comment: Sorry, my html is not valid..... XD
Thank you so much with your help and example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the .val() from the textarea, interpret as a jQuery object by wrapping it with the `$()` method and then filtering this object

```
var theTextareaHTML = $('#input').val();
var $HTMLasObject = $('<div/>').html(theTextareaHTML);
var contentFromblock1 = $HTMLasObject.find('#block1').text();
$('#output').val(contentFromblock1);
```

EDIT: Added the missing wrapper element, thanks to musefan

EDIT: Sorry, there was still a glitch. This one should do the trick (http://jsbin.com/ecuqug/1)

Answer (score -1):

To show the value of one textarea in another:

`$('#output').val($('#input').val());`

To show the inner HTML of one element in a textarea:

`$('#output').val($('#myelem').html());`

To show just the text:

`$('#output').val($('#myelem').text());`

[Click here to read about val().](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: This will not filter the HTML from inside the textarea. The first line will just copy the content completely. The two other lines won't work because the textarea HTML content is not part of the DOM

Comment: No? If you type HTML into a textarea and use `val()` to retrieve it, you can use that string containing HTML in another function such as `html()`.

Comment: It'd be really helpful if the OP actually explained what he wanted to do. I interpreted the question as "I want to take HTML from one textarea and insert it into another".

Comment: But the OP said that he wanted to copy only the content of `#block1` which is only part of the text content of the #input textarea and not part of the DOM

Answer (score -2):

try following:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var $inp = $("#input");    
  var $div = $("<div/>",{"html":$inp.val(), "id":"block1"});    
  $("#output").val( $div.html() + " By " + $div.attr("id"));
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3b5cV/2/

Comment: This will not filter the HTML from inside the textarea. It will just copy the content completely

Comment: still won't work. There are no #block1 or #block2 elements in the DOM

Comment: still a miss ... you copy the full textarea content into the div, then duplicate the id `block1`, which is already in the textarea HTML that you just copied